# A family of rank two bundles on $\mathbb CP^1$ parameterized by $H^1(O(-2n))$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Consider the family of extensions 
$$0\to O(-n)\to E\to O(n)\to 0,$$
parameterized by $H^1(O(-2n))$. For each element $e\in H^1(O(-2n))$ we get a rank two bundle $E$ that is of the form $O(-k)\oplus O(k)$ with $0\le k\le n$. Generic $E$ is isomorphic to $O\oplus O$.

**Question.** How to describe the stratification on $H^1(O(-2n))$ according to various $k$? Is there some nice reference working out this example?

Comment: Hint: the stratification is $GL_2$-invarriant.

Comment: Sasha, thanks! Since you make a hint, I would like to make a guess. Is the closure of the strata corresponding to $O(k)+O(-k)$ consists of all homogeneous polynomials of degree $2n-2$  with at least one root of multiplicity $k+1$?

Comment: No. The right answer is the following. A polynomial of degree $2n-2$ gives a symmetric bilinear form on polinomials of degree $n-1$ on the dual space. The stratification is by the rank of this bilinear form.